# Do Metapsionic Feats work with Aegis Energy Blast, Improved Ranged Attack, & Empowered Blast suit mod?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, psionics, metamagic

-Do Metapsionic Feats work with Aegis Energy Blast, Improved Ranged Attack, & Empowered Blast suit mod?

- Aegis' Energy Blast seems to emulate Energy Ray power. Are the following Metapsionic Feats applicable to it?....
- Empower Power
- Maximize Power
- Twin Power
- Quicken Power
- Split Psionic Ray

Answer (score 2):

While similar to *energy ray*, none of the aegis energy blast customization is not *energy ray*, nor any other psionic power. The aegis suit, along with its customizations, is a supernatural ability.

Note that the ranged customizations were intentionally on the low-power side. The author (who I have spoken with on this topic) said this was done because the aegis is “supposed to be” melee-oriented.